# OpenCV : the difference between mask and ROI

Tags: opencv, roi

I tried to set a ROI with angle in an image. At first, I thought that using a mask would give me the same result as setting the ROI in my IplImage structure. Then, I would just use cvResize the same way I did when I used ROI, but this time for a mask.

However, this is obviously not this easy, because of the angle.

Is there any way to copy the inside of any rectangle, at any angle, into a new IplImage, which would be of the size of this very rectangle?

```c
CvSeq* approximatedContour = cvApproxPoly(currentContour,
                                          sizeof(CvContour),
                                          0,
                                          CV_POLY_APPROX_DP,
                                          8);

// Circonscrire le polygone trouve dans un rectangle
etiquetteBox = cvMinAreaRect2(approximatedContour);

CvPoint2D32f boxPoints[4];
CvPoint2D32f* c1 = (&cvPoint2D32f(0,0),
                    &cvPoint2D32f(200,0),
                    &cvPoint2D32f(0,200),
                    &cvPoint2D32f(200,200));

CvMat* mmat = cvCreateMat(3,3,CV_32FC1);

cvBoxPoints(etiquetteBox, boxPoints);

IplImage* mask = cvCreateImage(cvSize(in->width,in->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
IplImage* ROIimg = cvCreateImage(cvSize(in->width,in->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
drawBox(mask,etiquetteBox,target_color[3]);

cvAnd(thresImg,mask,ROIimg,mask);
if(voirSeuillage)
    cvCvtColor(ROIimg,in,CV_GRAY2BGR); //ROIimg is OK here!

mmat = cvGetPerspectiveTransform(boxPoints,c1,mmat);
cvWarpPerspective(ROIimg,thresImgResized,mmat); // here I get a full black image!
```

Doing this, as kindly suggested by Banthar, I get a full black image instead of what is delimited by boxPoints in ROIimg, what's wrong with this code?

### After applying answer:

Here is what I do now :

```c
double angle = 0.;
// TODO adaptive angle compensation
if(abs(etiquetteBox.angle) > 30)
    angle = etiquetteBox.angle + 270.;
else
    angle = etiquetteBox.angle - 270.;

CvPoint2D32f boxPoints[4];
CvPoint2D32f c1[] = {cvPoint2D32f(0,0),
                     cvPoint2D32f(20,0),
                     cvPoint2D32f(20,20),
                     cvPoint2D32f(0,20)};

CvMat* mmat = cvCreateMat(3,3,CV_32FC1);
cvBoxPoints(etiquetteBox, boxPoints);
Point center = Point(10,10);

//warp the image to fit the polygon into the 20x20 image
mmat = cvGetPerspectiveTransform(boxPoints,c1,mmat);
cvWarpPerspective(thresImg,thresImgResized,mmat);
//rotate the image because the inconsistent angle of etiquetteBox
// from a frame to the next ...
//it would be very cool to find a way to fix this...
CvMat rot_mat = getRotationMatrix2D( center, angle,1.0);
cvWarpAffine(thresImgResized,rotatedIm,&rot_mat);
It is still not quite what I want, because the object is rotating into the 20x20 rotatedImg; in thresImgResized, after cvWarpPerspective, the object is well segmented, BUT it is reversed because the inconsistency of the angle of etiquetteBox (-0 degrees in a frame, -90 in the next, depending on how I hold the object to be detected), which I get this way:

cvFindContours(dilImage,
               contoursStorage,
               &contours,
               sizeof(CvContour),
               CV_RETR_LIST,
               CV_CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_KCOS);

// Trouver des polygones
CvSeq* currentContour = contours;
while(currentContour != 0 && !etiquette)
{
    CvSeq* approximatedContour = cvApproxPoly(currentContour,
                                              sizeof(CvContour),
                                              0,
                                              CV_POLY_APPROX_DP,
                                              9);

    // Circonscrire le polygone trouve dans un rectangle
    etiquetteBox = cvMinAreaRect2(approximatedContour);
```

I don't know how to fix this, but, at least, it is better than setting my IplImage ROI, because I compensate the etiquetteBox's angle switch from -0 to -90 degrees in consecutive frames.

Comment: You can do it with `cvGetPerspectiveTransform` and `cvWarpPerspective`.

Comment: in CvMat* cvGetPerspectiveTransform(const CvPoint2D32f* src, const CvPoint2D32f* dst, CvMat* mapMatrix), src would be my 4 points in my boxPoints, and dst the points [0,0], [0,destImg->width], [destImg->height,0], [destImg->height,destImg->width] ?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure about the order of vertices, but you will see if you need to swap them.

Comment: I googled on it a little, the order of vertices seems to be good; however it acts strangely, I get a full white image... see my edit above

Comment: Actually I get a full black image...

Comment: Transformation seems correct. I'm not sure what `cvAnd` is supposed to do. Check if `ROIimg` contains expected image.

Comment: Yes it does, I check this here : cvCvtColor(ROIimg,in,CV_GRAY2BGR); Even if I try it on another image, like my first image in, thresImgResized is always black

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7207/discussion-between-banthar-and-ctzstef)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong brackets in definition of `c1`. Try this:

```
    CvPoint2D32f c1[] = {
                        cvPoint2D32f(0,200),
                        cvPoint2D32f(0,0),
                        cvPoint2D32f(200,0),
                        cvPoint2D32f(200,200),
    };
```